# Azure Data Factory to Salesforce upsert, required field missing error

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am working on a pipeline that will load data generated in a stored procedure to Salesforce using the copy activity upsert functionality.

I have this working however, if I modify the Stored Procedure like add a UNION to the existing query.  I all of a sudden start getting the following error message

```
ErrorCode=SalesforceOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Salesforce Operation Failed: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING:Required fields are missing: [ERROR_EXAMPLE_FIELD]:ERROR_EXAMPLE_FIELD --,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SalesforceConnector,'
```

However, that field exists in my SP and was never modified or moved.

I have set my upsert id to "ID" which I was told was the key for this object.  I tried the missing field as well but that didn't work.

I've verified the field is in my Stored Procedure.  I also re-did the copy activity in ADF from scratch.

If I revert my Stored Procedure changes it will work.  However, I need these changes.

Stored Procedure

```
SELECT 
          curated.[Id]
        , curated.[ERROR_EXAMPLE_FIELD]  
FROM curated_hash curated
LEFT JOIN staging Staging
    ON curated.id = Staging.Id 
WHERE curated.Hash_id != staging.Hash_id

UNION

SELECT 
          verify_new_record.[Id]
        , verify_new_record.[ERROR_EXAMPLE_FIELD]
FROM verify_new_record
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce spits that error if `[ERROR_EXAMPLE_FIELD]` is set to `NOT NULL (required)`, but a single row is `NULL` in your SP's result set.

I recommend to check that all rows returned by your SP contain `[ERROR_EXAMPLE_FIELD]`.

Comment: I edited to avoid the impression that you are asking a question (for which a comment should be used, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). In case I broke the intended meaning of your post feel free to [edit], undo and fix. But please keep in mind [answer] and that you should not misuse answer posts for asking clarification questions.